# Parameter or attribute?

Tags: differences

"The height of the chair is 1m" - Can I say that "the height" is an attribute of the chair? Or much better to say it's a parameter? Can I say, that "the height" is a feature or a characteristic or property?

UPD. So, I understand that it can't be: 
A:Describe the **parametres** of the chair.
B: The **height** of the chairis 1m.

Yes? it has to be: 
A:Describe the **attributes** of the chair. 
B: The **height** of the chairis 1m"

Comment: Yes, you can pretty much do any of those.  It's a judgment call on your point as to which term has the most appropriate connotation in your context (keeping in mind you want to remain consistent with usages elsewhere in the surrounding context).

Comment: @Hot Licks And a additional question: what a word better to use talking about hight of things: attribute or property?

Comment: Same answer as above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Attribute is a quality of the item. Parameter is the measure of the quality.

Say Ram is a boy. His height is a attribute. 6'2 foot is the parameter of that attribute.

Comment: Does this mean that a parameter is an attribute value?

Answer (score 0):

If the question is "Can I say that *height* is an attribute of the chair?", the answer is yes, it's an **attribute** (or characteristic). But 1m is a measurable **parameter**.

So if you need to ask a question about how high a chair is, you're asking about a *parameter*:

Q: Describe the *parameters* of the chair.
A: It's 1m high and weighs 4.5kg.

For example, in an experiment on chair ergonomics researchers measured the height of a specific chair:

> For each subject the following **parameters** were measured in sitting
>   posture by means of a special chair seat:
>
> - **stool height**

Comment: "- Tell me about chair's attributes. - It's small and soft." "- Tell me about chair's parameteres. - Its height is 1m and..." Yes?

Comment: After the edit, I understand your question better. Yes, the chair's attributes include its height, weight and other characteristics. But parameters are 1m 20cm, 5.8kg, etc.

Comment: A measure of *softness* would also be a parameter. The word for measurements of *size* is [**dimensions**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/dimension).

Comment: @JHCL "dimensions" is more specific, no doubt, but why not "parameter"? Works fine too, IMO.

Comment: @A.P. Yes, I'm not disagreeing. Parameters can be applied to all measurable attributes of a thing.